# How do I add extra rows to each column across all groups in tibble using tidyverse?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

How do I add extra rows for all columns (except the grouping variable) for each group `id` in the data frame?

Data:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> df <- tibble(id = c("A", "B", "C"), day = c(3, 1, 2), station = c(10, 9, 2))
> df
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  id      day station
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         3      10
2 B         1       9
3 C         2       2
```

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   id [3]
  id      day station
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         2       9
2 A         3      10
3 B         0       8
4 B         1       9
5 C         1       1
6 C         2       2
```

I could change `day` using:

```
> df %>% group_by(id) %>% complete(day = (day - 1):day)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   id [3]
  id      day station
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         2      NA
2 A         3      10
3 B         0      NA
4 B         1       9
5 C         1      NA
6 C         2       2
```

But I couldn't use `mutate` appropriately to do this for `station` as well as since I don't know *how to refer to each column* inside `complete` properly:

Failed attempt:

```
> df %>% 
+ group_by(id) %>% 
+ mutate(across(c("day", "station"), complete((.x - 1):.x)))
```

Comment: So what you would like to achieve is not manually adding arbitrary rows but rather programmatically create rows based on a function that takes existing values as an input? Or is your question specifically about how to use `complete()` across various columns?

Comment: @dufei For the moment, I only wish to know how to use `complete()` across various columns. However, adding rows programmatically using values in a particular column is an interesting use case well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your desired output:

```
df %>% 
bind_rows(df %>% mutate(across(c('day', 'station'), ~.x - 1 ))) %>% 
arrange(id)

# A tibble: 6 × 3
# id      day station
# <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A         3      10
# 2 A         2       9
# 3 B         1       9
# 4 B         0       8
# 5 C         2       2
# 6 C         1       1
```

Here I'm appending the same dataframe but with mutated columns, so:

```
df %>% mutate(across(c('day', 'station'), ~.x - 1 ))
```

Is:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  id      day station
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         2       9
2 B         0       8
3 C         1       1
```

Then with [`bind_rows`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html), I'm appending those rows to the original data frame, which brings:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  id      day station
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         3      10
2 B         1       9
3 C         2       2
4 A         2       9
5 B         0       8
6 C         1       1
```

Finally I just arrange by `id` so the rows look like your example.

Comment: If you need something more generic, let me know

Comment: Of course, let me edit my post

Comment: Now there's an explanation

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying ThomasIsCoding's answer:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(across(day:station, ~ .x - 1:0))
```

I don't think it has any advantage to use `complete()` here if you just want to increment values and do not have a specific range for each group.

Comment: cool! I forgot about `summarize`, super answer! +1!

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option simplifies the problem

```
> library(data.table)

> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, `-`, 1:0), id]
   id day station
1:  A   2       9
2:  A   3      10
3:  B   0       8
4:  B   1       9
5:  C   1       1
6:  C   2       2
```

---

Or, using `list` + `unnest`

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(day:station, ~ list(.x - (1:0)))) %>%
  unnest(day:station) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  id      day station
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         2       9
2 A         3      10
3 B         0       8
4 B         1       9
5 C         1       1
6 C         2       2
```